# How to scan for Bluetooth low energy devices using bluez API

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm new in programming Bluetooth low energy using BlueZ.

I want to develop a native code c to scan nearby devices using a BlueZ API for Bluetooth low energy under Android 4.0.3.

Anyone know which BlueZ methods I should use?

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking to write native c code to scan BLE devices, your best option would be to get the bluez package from [here](http://www.bluez.org/) and look at how that is implemented. For scanning for devices, see the /tools/hcitool.c source file, specifically the function static `void cmd_lescan(int dev_id, int argc, char **argv)` and understand how that is implemented.

I hope this helps.